# lidR:::catalog_laxindex() - "largest interval gap increased to..." logged

Tags: las, lidr, log

Often when running `lidR:::catalog_laxindex()` on a catalog of tiles I'm seeing the following log messages:

```
largest interval gap increased to 1554
largest interval gap increased to 3802
largest interval gap increased to 15080
largest interval gap increased to 3921
```

while the function is running. The function runs successfully to completion, so should I worry about these messages or ignore them?

Comment: I have encountered this message when normalizing point cloud data. Could you please describe how you read in the las data and any preprocessing/filters you apply? Is there a link to the dataset your are working with? If you can help us replicate the issue, that would be great.

Comment: I apologize for the misleading post. These log messages are actually coming from `lidR:::catalog_laxindex()`, which I run just prior to normalizing.

Comment: Ok so it is nothing. You would have the same message with laxindex from lastool. This come from laslib code. catalog_laxindex basically wraps the code of lasindex in R